# How to align the baseline and border of two divs

Tags: css, flexbox

I am stuck on this seemingly simple CSS problem. There are two divs, both have the same height and same font size, but different fonts. My goal is simply to verticall align the baseline and the borders of both divs.

Here is the first attempt:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.d1, .d2 {
  
  height: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 14px;
}


.d1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}


.d2 {
  font-family: Roboto Mono, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">0</div>
  <div class="d2">0</div>
</div>
```

If we take a close look, the baseline is off by one pixel:

[image]

Now the same snippet with `align-items: baseline;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}


.d1, .d2 {
  
  height: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 14px;
}


.d1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}


.d2 {
  font-family: Roboto Mono, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">0</div>
  <div class="d2">0</div>
</div>
```

Now the basline is aligned, but the borders do not match anymore:

[image]

Is there a simple way to align the text of both divs while keeping the borders aligned?

Comment: Essentially no. the font glyphs are designed differently. Frankly though **no-one** will notice a 1px difference.

Comment: Try `align-content: baseline;` at the place of  `align-items: baseline;`.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Thanks, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is to manually adjust the position of one of them. You won't find a generic solution that work for all the cases:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Potta+One&family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap');
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background:linear-gradient(red 0 0) 0 75%/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.d1,
.d2 {
  height: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.d1 {
  font-family: 'Potta One', cursive;
}

.d2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.d1 span {
  vertical-align: 0.08em; /* your custom value based on your fonts*/
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1"><span>0</span></div>
  <div class="d2">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I found another solution that is more suitable for my specific application case. Will post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution that does what I want it to do.

The important part for me is the border between the two `div` elements. This is now represented by a third element, which uses `self-align: stretch` so it has the full container height. The other two `div` elements are aligned by the container's `align-items: baseline` attribute to make sure they have the same baseline. Also, different to the original snipped the outer border is applied to the container.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid blue;    
}


.d1, .d2 { 
  vertical-align: bottom;
  right: 20px;
}


.d1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}


.d2 {
  font-family: Roboto Mono, sans-serif;
}

.separator {
  align-self: stretch;
  width: 0;
  height: auto;
  border-right: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">0</div>
  <div class="separator">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="d2">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: without extra element: https://jsfiddle.net/jL218m9s/

Comment: @TemaniAfif That is much better. But as I see it there is no need for the inset shadow, this can be done with a normal border.

Answer (score -1):

try this **border-right : none;** for 0ne div element
and **border-left:none;** for another div element

Comment: That will not help for vertical alignment.

Comment: @Narasimha Suggestions that don't actually answer the question shouldn't be posted as answers, but only as comments on other people's posts. You may need to build enough reputation on the website first before you can do this.